# How Order by is not working with partion by?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

```sql
select a.* 
from (
  select lname,
         lstatus,
         ltime,
         lid,
         row_number() over(partition by ltime,lstatus,lid order by ltime desc) as rm 
  from sortdata
) 
a where a.rm=1;
```

The result of the above query is:

```
jo  doc 10/10/2019  211 1
jo  doc 11/10/2019  211 1
jo  roc 12/10/2019  211 1
jo  woc 13/10/2019  211 1
```

while the datatype of ltime is dat , please suggest .

Comment: Please explain what results you want.

Comment: Question is unclear. can you share a sample input and output you expect ?

Comment: Are you wanting one row per date, status and id? If so, `trunc(ltime)` in the partition by should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `partition by`.  If you want one row per `lid`:

```
select a.*
from (select lname, lstatus, ltime, lid,
             row_number() over( partition by lid order by ltime desc) as rn
      from sortdata
     ) a
where a.rn = 1;
```

By including `ltime`, you are limiting the partition size to one row.  Hence, the `row_number()` value is `1` for all rows in the partition (there is only one of them).